# How to set launchMode on android launcher shortcut

Tags: android, android-intent, android-launcher

Im having trouble that the shurtcut created dynamically does not act like the original app shortcut/icon. The original app-launcher shortcut is defined to have launchmode=default, which make the app only have one single instance. If the user clicks the original icon, the app opens normally, and if user tries to click the launcher icon again, the app is not started in an new instance but the first instance is brought to front.

The problem is that I can not recreate this behaveour when creating a shortcut dymaically. The created shortcut create a new instance of the app every time the launcher icon is clicked. This is not intended, as it can result in having multiple instances of the same screen open simultaniously.

Anyone got a clue how to make the shortcut created put the already opened instance of the app to front instead of always creating a new instance?

If i run `installShortcut("green");`

a new shortcut is actually created on the home-screen, but it simply doesn't work as intended.

```
private void installShortcut(String color) {
    Logcat.d(color);
    if (Pref.getShortcutInstalled(this) != null) {
        uninstallShortcut();
    }
    Parcelable icon = getIcon(color);
    Intent install = createInstallIntent(icon);
    getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(install);
    String str = getString(R.string.installed_shortcut);
    String msg = str.replace("%var1", getString(R.string.app_name));
    Toaster.toast(this, msg);
    Pref.setShortcutInstalled(this, color);
    Api.count(this, "install_shortcut|install_shortcut_" + color);
}

private void uninstallShortcut() {
    Intent uninstall = createUnInstallIntent();
    getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(uninstall);
}

private Intent createUnInstallIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, createMainIntent());
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, getString(R.string.app_name));
    return intent;
}

private Parcelable getIcon(String color) {
    Parcelable icon = getIconParcelable(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    if ("blue".equals(color)) {
        icon = getIconParcelable(R.drawable.ic_launcher_blue);
    } else if ("purple".equals(color)) {
        icon = getIconParcelable(R.drawable.ic_launcher_purple);
    } else if ("green".equals(color)) {
        icon = getIconParcelable(R.drawable.ic_launcher_green);
    } else if ("orange".equals(color)) {
        icon = getIconParcelable(R.drawable.ic_launcher_orange);
    }
    return icon;
}

private Parcelable getIconParcelable(int resourceId) {
    return Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(this, resourceId);
}

private Intent createInstallIntent(Parcelable icon) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, getString(R.string.app_name));
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, createMainIntent());
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, icon);
    intent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    intent.putExtra("duplicate", true);
    return intent;
}


private Intent createMainIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    return intent;
}
```

UPDATE:

Found alternativ way that works better on more devices.

```
   public void addShortcut(Context context, String color) {
        //deleteShortcut(this);
        Intent shortcut = new Intent("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
        ApplicationInfo appInfo = context.getApplicationInfo();
        shortcut.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, context.getString(R.string.app_name));
        shortcut.putExtra("duplicate", false); // Just create once
        ComponentName component = new ComponentName(appInfo.packageName, appInfo.packageName+".activity.MainActivity");
        shortcut.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).setComponent(component));
        int res = getIconRes(color);
        Intent.ShortcutIconResource iconResource = Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(context, res);
        shortcut.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, iconResource);
        context.sendBroadcast(shortcut);
    }

    private int getIconRes(String color) {
        int res = R.mipmap.ic_launcher;
        if ("blue".equals(color)) {
            res = R.drawable.ic_launcher_blue;
        } else if ("purple".equals(color)) {
            res = R.drawable.ic_launcher_purple;
        } else if ("green".equals(color)) {
            res = R.drawable.ic_launcher_green;
        } else if ("orange".equals(color)) {
            res = R.drawable.ic_launcher_orange;
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: tried to call `intent.addFlags(...)` inside `createMainIntent()` ?

Comment: thanks, that might be a clue. Tried it but still does not affect the way the icon works on most devices/emulators. But found another way to add a shortcut on a blog, which seems to work better on many devices (but still not all). (se  update)

Comment: btw why are you using some undocumented action `"com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"` instead of `Intent#ACTION_CREATE_SHORTCUT` ?